# Script to insert default values to MANY-TO-MANY relation in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-insert

I'm using `SQL Server 2008`. Consider the following tables:

Table **STUDENT**

```
╔════╦═══════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ FIRSTNAME ║ LASTNAME ║
╠════╬═══════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║ joe       ║ Smith    ║
║  2 ║ frank     ║ Smith    ║
║  3 ║ Scott     ║ Smith    ║
╚════╩═══════════╩══════════╝
```

Table **COURSE**

```
╔════╦═════════╦════════════════╗
║ ID ║  NAME   ║  DESCRIPTION   ║
╠════╬═════════╬════════════════╣
║  1 ║ Physics ║ PHYSICS COURSE ║
║  2 ║ MATH    ║ COURSE         ║
╚════╩═════════╩════════════════╝
```

TABLE **STUDENT_COURSE**

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ STUDENT_ID ║ COURSE_ID ║ GRADE ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║          1 ║         1 ║     9 ║
║          2 ║         1 ║     8 ║
║          3 ║         1 ║     6 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```

I need to insert default grade 10 to all users for MATH course, if such grade does not exist for that user.

I'm not familiar with Microsoft SQL Server and T-SQL. Can you please help me with such query?

Comment: Microsoft's product is called **SQL Server**, and its query language "dialect" is **T-SQL** (Transact-SQL)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO STUDENT_COURSE (Student_ID, course_ID, grade)
SELECT  a.ID as StudentID, b.ID as Course_ID, 10 AS grade
FROM    Student a 
        CROSS JOIN Course b
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
            SELECT  d.*
            FROM    STUDENT_COURSE d
                    INNER JOIN Course e
                        ON d.Course_ID = e.ID
            WHERE   e.Name = 'Math'
        ) c ON  a.ID = c.student_ID AND
                b.ID = c.course_ID 
WHERE   c.student_ID IS NULL AND 
        b.Name = 'Math'
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fb4bb/1)
- [SQLFiddle Demo (*added record which one student has already grade on MATH*)](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c936a/1)

OUTPUT if you List all the records on table `STUDENT_COURSE`

```
MySQL> SELECT * FROM STUDENT_COURSE

╔════════════╦═══════════╦═══════╗
║ STUDENT_ID ║ COURSE_ID ║ GRADE ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬═══════╣
║          1 ║         1 ║     9 ║
║          2 ║         1 ║     8 ║
║          3 ║         1 ║     6 ║
║          1 ║         2 ║    10 ║
║          2 ║         2 ║    10 ║
║          3 ║         2 ║    10 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩═══════╝
```